# How does Toad Rally multiplayer work?

Tags: super-mario-run

I was wondering a little because I read it's not real time but the other player is a ghost and I also never receive invitations - I always select the other players. There are also no waiting times and apparently the other players never give up?

If players are not playing at the same time, how can the end score be calculated immediately?

How does it work? Anybody knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you race against someone in Toad Rally, you are racing against a previous run of another player.

For example, you run a Toad Rally against a (random) player. When the run is over, the data from that run (when you jumped, the coins and items you collected, the number and color of Toads you got) is sent to Nintendo's servers. Later, I start a new Toad Rally game and select you from the list of potential opponents. The game will download the data from your run from Nintendo's servers, and use that to move the character representing your run. Since all of this data is stored from your original run, the game can use that to calculate the score of both players at the end of the run.

Comment: Interesting. Does this mean also that the first runs were done by Nintendo's staff/added artificially? Also, it means that the other player isn't in reality winning or losing anything when I run against them. And finally that other players are still able to compete against my worst runs.

Comment: @Ixx While I was writing this, I wondered how the first runs were setup as well. I assume that Nintendo has plenty of data from when they were testing the game, so they probably seeded it with that.

Comment: Hmm this spoils the fun a little. Real time is slower to start and more complicated but it would be nicer to know I'm truly competing with someone (now, me against them) :/ but the friends rally at least (haven't played it so far) should be real time right?

Comment: @lxx Nope, it works exactly the same way. Only difference is it doesn't cost tickets, and you don't keep the toads you earn.